# How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, match

Is there any function that would be the equivalent of a combination of `df.isin()` and `df[col].str.contains()`?

For example, say I have the series
`s = pd.Series(['cat','hat','dog','fog','pet'])`, and I want to find all places where `s` contains any of `['og', 'at']`, I would want to get everything but 'pet'.

I have a solution, but it's rather inelegant:

```
searchfor = ['og', 'at']
found = [s.str.contains(x) for x in searchfor]
result = pd.DataFrame[found]
result.any()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *Note*: There is a solution [described by @unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600345/9209546) which is more efficient than using `pd.Series.str.contains`. If performance is an issue, then this may be worth investigating.

Comment: Highly recommend checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207) for partial string search using multiple keywords/regexes (scroll down to the "**Multiple Substring Search**" subheading).

Comment: In the specific example in the question, you could use `pd.Series.str.endswith` with a tuple argument: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html

Answer (score 446, accepted):

One option is just to use the regex `|` character to try to match each of the substrings in the words in your Series `s` (still using `str.contains`).

You can construct the regex by joining the words in `searchfor` with `|`:

```
>>> searchfor = ['og', 'at']
>>> s[s.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
0    cat
1    hat
2    dog
3    fog
dtype: object
```

As @AndyHayden noted in the comments below, take care if your substrings have special characters such as `$` and `^` which you want to match literally. These characters have specific meanings in the context of regular expressions and will affect the matching.

You can make your list of substrings safer by escaping non-alphanumeric characters with `re.escape`:

```
>>> import re
>>> matches = ['$money', 'x^y']
>>> safe_matches = [re.escape(m) for m in matches]
>>> safe_matches
['\\$money', 'x\\^y']
```

The strings with in this new list will match each character literally when  used with `str.contains`.

Comment: maybe good to add this link http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings too. Starting from pandas 0.15, the string operations are even easier

Comment: one thing you have to take care with is if a string in searchfor has special regex characters (you can [map with re.escape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python)).

Comment: I don't know why your method doesn't work with "str.startswith('|'.join(searchfor))"

Comment: in this case I understand we use "|" for OR, how could we use AND??

Answer (score 107):

You can use `str.contains` alone with a regex pattern using `OR (|)`:

```
s[s.str.contains('og|at')]
```

Or you could add the series to a `dataframe` then use `str.contains`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df[s.str.contains('og|at')]
```

**Output:**

```
0 cat
1 hat
2 dog
3 fog
```

Comment: how to do it for AND?

Comment: @JacoSolari check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation

Comment: @James yes, thanks. For completion here is the most upvoted oneliner in that answer.
`df.col.str.contains(r'(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)',regex=True)`

Answer (score 15):

Here is a one line lambda that also works:

```
df["TrueFalse"] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: 1 if any(i in x for i in searchfor) else 0)
```

Input:

```
searchfor = ['og', 'at']

df = pd.DataFrame([('cat', 1000.0), ('hat', 2000000.0), ('dog', 1000.0), ('fog', 330000.0),('pet', 330000.0)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

   col1  col2
0   cat 1000.0
1   hat 2000000.0
2   dog 1000.0
3   fog 330000.0
4   pet 330000.0
```

Apply Lambda:

```
df["TrueFalse"] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: 1 if any(i in x for i in searchfor) else 0)
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2        TrueFalse
0   cat     1000.0      1
1   hat     2000000.0   1
2   dog     1000.0      1
3   fog     330000.0    1
4   pet     330000.0    0
```

Comment: I did it as `df.loc[df.col1.apply(lambda x: True if any(i in x for i in searchfor) else False)]` and it gone well, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Without making it too complex, you can add `|` in between each entry, like `fieldname.str.contains("cat|dog")` works

Comment: Hi there  This solution was already provided (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26578218/12439119), try not to duplicate answers.