# pandas dataframe str.contains() AND operation

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a df (Pandas Dataframe) with three rows:

```
some_col_name
"apple is delicious"
"banana is delicious"
"apple and banana both are delicious"
```

The function `df.col_name.str.contains("apple|banana")` will catch all of the rows:

```
"apple is delicious",
"banana is delicious",
"apple and banana both are delicious".
```

How do I apply AND operator to the `str.contains()` method, so that it only grabs strings that contain BOTH "apple" & "banana"?

```
"apple and banana both are delicious"
```

I'd like to grab strings that contains 10-20 different words (grape, watermelon, berry, orange, ..., etc.)

Comment: The example is toy because you only have K=2 substrings and they occur in-order: apple, banana. But you're really asking for a method that **matches K=10-20 substrings, in any order**. Regex with multiple lookahead assertions is the way to go (@Anzel's solution).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
df[(df['col_name'].str.contains('apple')) & (df['col_name'].str.contains('banana'))]
```

Answer (score 47):

You can also do it in regex expression style:

```
df[df['col_name'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)')]
```

You can then, build your list of words into a regex string like so:

```
base = r'^{}'
expr = '(?=.*{})'
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'cat']  # example
base.format(''.join(expr.format(w) for w in words))
```

will render:

```
'^(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)(?=.*cat)'
```

Then you can do your stuff dynamically.

Comment: This is great. I tried doing it with f-strings. It turned out like this, do you have any improvements? `filter_string = '^' + ''.join(fr'(?=.*{w})' for w in words) `

Comment: @spen.smith I think your implementation is clear and simple; don’t think you need to improve it further unless you run into issue

Comment: Anzel solution is solid.  However, '^(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)' works fine but this might need to be modified if the order in which apple and banana may appear is not know before hand.  Something like this expression will do when the order is not known  '^(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)|^(?=.*banana)(?=.*apple)'.  Also, I would remove ^ to make it search for anywhere in the string not just in the begining.

Answer (score 38):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["apple is delicious",
                           "banana is delicious",
                           "apple and banana both are delicious"]})

targets = ['apple', 'banana']

# Any word from `targets` are present in sentence.
>>> df.col.apply(lambda sentence: any(word in sentence for word in targets))
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: col, dtype: bool

# All words from `targets` are present in sentence.
>>> df.col.apply(lambda sentence: all(word in sentence for word in targets))
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This solution is more flexible compared to df[df['col_name'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)')] but need to evaluate the time it would take compared to regex.

Comment: very pythonic indeed!

Answer (score 13):

This works

```
df.col.str.contains(r'(?=.*apple)(?=.*banana)',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to use native methods and avoid writing regexps, here is a vectorized version with no lambdas involved:

```
targets = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']
fruit_masks = (df['col'].str.contains(string) for string in targets)
combined_mask = np.vstack(fruit_masks).all(axis=0)
df[combined_mask]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex

```
apple.*banana|banana.*apple
```

**Code is:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,"apple is delicious"],[2,"banana is delicious"],[3,"apple and banana both are delicious"]],columns=('ID','String_Col'))

print df[df['String_Col'].str.contains(r'apple.*banana|banana.*apple')]
```

**Output**

```
   ID                           String_Col
2   3  apple and banana both are delicious
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to catch in the minimum atleast two words in the sentence, maybe this will work (taking the tip from @Alexander) :

```
target=['apple','banana','grapes','orange']
connector_list=['and']
df[df.col.apply(lambda sentence: (any(word in sentence for word in target)) & (all(connector in sentence for connector in connector_list)))]
```

output:

```
                                   col
2  apple and banana both are delicious
```

if you have more than two words to catch which are separated by comma ',' than add it to the connector_list and modify the second condition from all to any

```
df[df.col.apply(lambda sentence: (any(word in sentence for word in target)) & (any(connector in sentence for connector in connector_list)))]
```

output:

```
                                        col
2        apple and banana both are delicious
3  orange,banana and apple all are delicious
```

Answer (score 3):

Enumerating all possibilities for large lists is cumbersome. A better way is to use `reduce()` and the [bitwise AND](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746642/5858851) operator (`&`).

For example, consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["apple is delicious",
                       "banana is delicious",
                       "apple and banana both are delicious",
                       "i love apple, banana, and strawberry"]})

#                                    col
#0                    apple is delicious
#1                   banana is delicious
#2   apple and banana both are delicious
#3  i love apple, banana, and strawberry
```

Suppose we wanted to search for all of the following:

```
targets = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']
```

We can do:

```
#from functools import reduce  # needed for python3
print(df[reduce(lambda a, b: a&b, (df['col'].str.contains(s) for s in targets))])

#                                    col
#3  i love apple, banana, and strawberry
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create masks

```
apple_mask = df.colname.str.contains('apple')
bannana_mask = df.colname.str.contains('bannana')
df = df [apple_mask & bannana_mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

From @Anzel's answer, I wrote a function since I'm going to be applying this a lot:

```
def regify(words, base=str(r'^{}'), expr=str('(?=.*{})')):
    return base.format(''.join(expr.format(w) for w in words))
```

So if you have `words` defined:

```
words = ['apple', 'banana']
```

And then call it with something like:

```
dg = df.loc[
    df['col_name'].str.contains(regify(words), case=False, regex=True)
]
```

then you should get what you're after.