# Filtering DataFrame by finding exact word (not combined) in a column of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame has two columns:

```
Name  Status
 a    I am Good
 b    Goodness!!!
 c    Good is what i feel
 d    Not Good-at-all
```

I want to filter rows in which Status has a string 'Good' as its exact word, not combined with any other words or characters.

So the output will be:

```
Name  Status
a    i am Good
c    Good is what i feel
```

Two other rows had a 'Good' string in it but mixed with other characters, so should not be picked up.

I tried doing:

```
d = df[df['Status'].str.contains('Good')]  # But all rows come up
```

I believe some regex like `(r'\bGood\b', Status)` will do that, but this is not able to sum it up together. And how/where exactly can I fit the regex in a DataFrame filter condition to achieve this? And how to achieve `startswith` or `endswith` 'Good' (exact word search)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're defining "exact" to mean no other characters (including punctuation which defines a word boundary `\b`), you could instead check for a leading and trailing space and/or beginning/end anchors:

```
>>> df[df['Status'].str.contains(r'(?:\s|^)Good(?:\s|$)')]
  Name               Status
0    a            I am Good
2    c  Good is what i feel
```

Explanation:

- `(?:\s|^)` is a non-capturing group looking for a space character (`\s`) or the beginning of the string (`^`).
- `Good` is the word you're looking for.
- `(?:\s|$)` is a non-capturing group looking for a space character (`\s`) or the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: @ajcr-Thanks , i am accepting your answer, but as you mentioned with exact i can include some special chars like ! ?...So  i am curious  about how i will allow some/few chars combined with 'Good' like "Good`s" or 'Good!'. Can u please help.

Comment: You could make a character class of characters that are allowed to follow 'good', for example `! ? '`. The second character class would then be  `"(?:[\s!?']|$)"`.

Comment: @AlexRiley Can you help me. I want to match only the specific string in rows. I have column with strings and I only want to count that exact string with regex? From the above answer it skips if it found `good.`

Answer (score 2):

Based on a similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37011978/10456915), you can also built your query dynamically as follows:

```
base = r'^{}'
expr = '(?:\s|^){}(?:,\s|$)'
string='Good'
df[df['Status'].str.contains(base.format(''.join(expr.format(string))))]
```

This has really helped me when filtering dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at normal text with commas in, it can also be useful to add the comma in as below.

```
df[df['Status'].str.contains(r'(?:\s|^)Good(?:,\s|$)')]
```