# pandas search for substring over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df such that

```
       c_name  f_name 
0      abc     abc12  
1      xyz     abc1  
2      mnq     mnq2
```

The goal is to find a substring across the two columns an know which column it belongs to. Preference should be to `c_name`, as in if the substring is in both the columns then `c_name` gets precedence For eg: if I search for `abc` in the above dataframe I should somehow get row 0 `abc` for `c_name` and row 1 `abc1` for `f_name`.

To solve this I started with 
`df[df['c_name'].str.contains('abc', case=False)]`
which will give me the results for `c_name`. The question now is to how to exclude the rows where I already have the results from performing the same operation on `f_name`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas dataframe str.contains() AND operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
row  =[['abcx','abcy'],
       ['efg','abcz'],
       ['higj','UK']]
df= pd.DataFrame(row)
df.columns = ['c_name', 'f_name']

print df[df['c_name'].str.contains('abc', case=False)]

delta_df =df[~df['c_name'].str.contains('abc', case=False)]
print delta_df[delta_df['f_name'].str.contains('abc', case=False)]
```

output

```
  c_name f_name
0   abcx   abcy
  c_name f_name
1    efg   abcz
```

Answer (score 2):

- `stack` into a series
- `str.contains` to get truth value of sub string
- `unstack` to get back dataframe
- subset results to ensure at least one match
- `idxmax(1)` gets first `True` in columns

---

```
def find_subtext(df, txt):
    contains = df.stack().str.contains(txt).unstack()
    return contains[contains.any(1)].idxmax(1)
```

---

```
find_subtext(df, 'abc')

0    c_name
1    f_name
dtype: object
```

---

```
df.assign(abc=find_subtext(df, 'abc'))

  c_name f_name     abc
0    abc  abc12  c_name
1    xyz   abc1  f_name
2    mnq   mnq2     NaN
```

Comment: I can always rely on you to come through with a response :) Thank you very much. Its an interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

Mark your first search result as something like 2. This will be overridden(by 1) if the new search result meets.

Comment: how is the question :) I know what to do, I just dont know how to do it since I am not proficient at pandas

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way:

1. concatenate the target "string" columns into a new single column, e.g.

   ```
   df['new_col'] = df['c_name'] + ' ' + df['f_name']
   ```
2. search the `new_col` for the substring, e.g.

   ```
   result = df[df['new_col'].str.contains('abc')]
   ```
3. delete `new_col` after it has completed its mission:

   ```
   del results['new_col']
   ```

---

Here is an example:

```
>>> df= pd.DataFrame(row, columns=['c_name', 'f_name'])
>>> df
  c_name f_name
0   abcx   abcy
1    efg   abcz
2   higj     UK
>>> df['new_col'] = df['c_name'] + ' ' + df['f_name']
>>> results = df[df['new_col'].str.contains('abc')]
>>> del df['new_col'], results['new_col']
>>> results
  c_name f_name
0   abcx   abcy
1    efg   abcz
```