# Selecting rows from a dataframe using a list of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of values that I would like to use to select rows in a dataframe. The trick is I would like to select any row where the list value is in the row. Example:

```
index    color    shape
 1       blue     star
 2       red      square
 3       yellow   circle
```

My list would be

```
list_vals = ['sq', 'blu']
```

I would like to select the rows

```
index    color   shape
1        blue    star
2        red     square
```

Comment: Could you explain how you selected index 3? It seems that row does not contain the required search terms in `list_vals`.

Comment: I think he meant index 1 in this case

Comment: Yes sorry, not paying enough attention. I am interested in selecting index 1 and 2. I have made edits to the original post.

Comment: @MorganGladden, no problem. Thanks for your edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or join the list with a pipe and check with `str.contains()` over the df:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(list_vals))).any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
       color   shape
index              
1      blue    star
2       red  square
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to convert to a `Series`, then use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to find the strings your interested in - we'll use `'|'.join` to create a regex 'OR' patter combining all items from `list_items`.

For reference, this regex pattern looks like `'sq|blu'` in this case.

Next, [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to get back to original shape and use [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) over axis 1 to create the boolean index we'll use to return the desired rows.

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('|'.join(list_vals)).unstack().any(1)]
```

[out]

```
   ndex color   shape
0     1  blue    star
1     2   red  square
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach

```
df_filtered = (
    df[(df['color'].str.contains(list_vals[0])) |
        (df['shape'].str.contains(list_vals[1]))
        ]
                )

print(df_filtered)
   index color   shape
0      1  blue    star
1      2   red  square
```

**EDIT**

Another approach is based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710092/4057186) (which contains the full explanation of this method)

- the only changes I made were (1) to join your search list into a single search string and (2) to return the `DataFrame` (row) index of the search (filtered) results (this is then used to slice the original `DataFrame`)

```
def find_subtext(df, txt):
    contains = df.stack().str.contains(txt).unstack()
    return contains[contains.any(1)].index
df_filtered = find_subtext(df, '|'.join(list_vals))

print(df.iloc[df_filtered, :])
   index color   shape
0      1  blue    star
1      2   red  square
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df['shape'].apply(lambda x: any(s in x[:len(s)] for s in list_vals))]
```

**Output**

```
  color   shape
1   red  square
```