# How to take a list of items and create a condition using them all

Tags: python, pandas, function

So basically I want to create a function that takes in a bunch of strings, checks if a particular column has that string then returns a boolean expression. I can easily do this with a single string. But I'm stumped on how to do it as a list of strings.

```
# Single String Example
def mask(x, df):
    return df.description.str.contains(x)
df[mask('sql')]

# Some kind of example of what I want
def mask(x, df):
    return df.description.str.contains(x[0]) & df.description.str.contains(x[1]) & df.description.str.contains(x[2]) & ...
df[mask(['sql'])]
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

So it looks like I figured out a way to do it, little unorthodox but seems to be working anyway. Solution below

```
def mask(x):
    X = np.prod([df.description.str.contains(i) for i in x], axis = 0)
    return [True if i == 1 else False for i in X]
my_selection = df[mask(['sql', 'python'], df)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas dataframe str.contains() AND operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out a solution here:

```
def mask(x):
    X = np.prod([df.description.str.contains(i) for i in x], axis = 0)
    return [True if i == 1 else False for i in X]
mine = df[mask(['sql', 'python'], df)]
```

A little unorthodox so if anyone has anything better will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
def mask(x, df):
    return df.description.str.contains(''.join(map('(?=.*%s)'.__mod__, x)))
df[mask(['a', 'b'], df)]
```

The `(?=.*<word>)` one after another is really an and operator.

Comment: Not sure why but it's giving a slightly different answer to if I was to try doing it manually

Comment: @HK Strange, how come?

Comment: @HK Can you try it again?

Comment: X = df.description.str.contains('sql'), 
Y = df.description.str.contains('python'), 
(X&Y).sum() ---

That gives me 31 rows, whereas the function for some reason gives 27 rows