# search keywords in dataframe cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I currently have a dataframe with a column that contains some words or chars, im trying to categorize each row by search keywords in that corresponding cell.

example

```
  words             |   category
-----------------------------------
im a test email     |  email
here is my handout  |  handout
```

here is what i have

```
conditions = [
        (df['words'].str.contains('flyer',False,regex=True)),
        (df['words'].str.contains('report',False,regex=True)),
        (df['words'].str.contains('form',False,regex=True)), 
        (df['words'].str.contains('scotia',False,regex=True)),  
        (df['words'].str.contains('news',False,regex=True)), 
         (df_prt_copy['words'].str.contains('questions.*\.pdf',False,regex=True)),
         .
         .
         .
         .
    ]
    choices = ['open house flyer', 
               'report', 
               'form', 
               'report',
               'news', 
               ‘question',
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
              ]
     df['category']=np.select(conditions, choices, default='others')
```

this works fine, but problem is that i have lots of keywords(probably over 120 or so), so maintaining this keywords list is very difficult, is there any better way to do this ? 
btw, i'm using python3

note: im looking for a easier method to manage a large list of keywords, which is different from simply a method to find keywords [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas) or [pandas dataframe str.contains() AND operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation?rq=1)

Comment: no, that is only suitable for small number of keywords, im looking for a easier method for a large list of keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join all your keywords and use `str.findall` in case you have multiple keywords in one line, and then `map` to a dict of cond vs choices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"words":["im a test email",
                            "here is my handout",
                            "This is a flyer"]})

choices = {"flyer":"open house flyer",
           "email":"email from someone",
           "handout":"some handout"}

df["category"] = df["words"].str.findall("|".join(choices.keys())).str.join(",").map(choices)

print (df)

#
                words            category
0     im a test email  email from someone
1  here is my handout        some handout
2     This is a flyer    open house flyer
```

Comment: could this be done with a dictionary? I’m having issue to match the sequence of keywords and corresponding categories when putting them together, because there are too many of them

Comment: I will test it today and get back here, thank you @Henry Yik

Comment: some words are embeded, for example "todayIgotAemailReport", this does not return "email" category, i guess this method dose not apply regex, any way to do it?

Comment: why doesn't it return email category?

Comment: i guess todayIgotAemailReport is one word which does not match word 'email', my original method has regex enabled, so this is not a problem

Comment: I take that you didn't even test it? [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html#pandas-series-str-findall) is equivalent to `re.findall`.

Comment: i did test it on all my keywords, otherwise how could i know the result? i actually compared with result from my original method, that's why i found it doesn't do regex somehow.   maybe there is somewhere or something wrong

Comment: It is not possible to fail extracting `email` from `todayIgotAemailReport` using `str.findall`, unless your key or messages contains capital letters, which can be solved by adding `flags=re.IGNORECASE` just like regular regex.

Comment: ok i just tested with your example with little change df = pd.DataFrame({"words":["im a test email",
                            "here is my handout",
                            "This is a emailflyer"]})
choices = {"flyer":"open house flyer",
           "email":"email from someone", 
           "handout":"some handout"}

df["category"] = df["words"].str.findall("|".join(choices.keys()),re.I).str.join(",").map(choices)

Comment: the result is following                   
"  This is a emailflyer         |        NaN"

Comment: Because there is no correct mapping for `email,flyer` in your `dict`.

Comment: oh i see what you meant now, thanks for clarifying, answer marked

Answer (score 1):

you can use flashtext..

```
 import pandas as pd
 from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

 keyword_dict = {
 'programming': ['python', 'pandas','java','java_football'],
 'sport': ['cricket','football','baseball']
 } 

 kp = KeywordProcessor()
 kp.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict)
 df = pd.DataFrame(['i love working in python','pandas is very popular library','i love playing football'],columns= ['text'])

 df['category'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: kp.extract_keywords(x, span_info = True))
```

[image]

now coming to problem for word like 'todayIgotAemailReport' you can refer to 
[How to split text without spaces into list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words,i) think this might help you for splitting any type of unknown join word

```
import wordninja
' '.join(wordninja.split('todayIgotAemailReport'))

#this will break this into their respective word which can make your stuff easy, while searching
#op
'today I got A email Report'
```

Comment: tried this method, but java_footbal does not get recognized

Comment: one more thing, this method only find first match, right?

Comment: also, i noticed that flashtext seems faster, but is there any way to do it with regex? right now as i tested, "todayIgotAemailReport" does not get recognized as email category

Comment: no , it will give you all match, kp.extract_keywords(x) this give list and i have selected item which is at index zero, that why when no keyword are found it is throwing error because list is empty

Comment: @ikel i have modified the code, and include span_info = True , so that you can get position of the word found

Answer (score 0):

You could have created `conditions` list dynamically. If you have a list of keywords, say `key_words`, you could `for` loop through the list of keywords, and `append` conditions like `(df['words'].str.contains(key_words[iter], False, regex=True))` to the list `conditions`.

Comment: in that case, i still have to match the sequence in "choices" list though, and that list is supposed to be like a category list, im hoping some way to possibly use dict to replace those 'choices' and 'condition' lists