# Display only the Specific Rows containing multiple words (with Logical operator-AND) in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text, nlp

I have a dataset(Dataframe) with multiple sentences/words in a Row. I want to extract those row data which consists of the given Specific Keyword. The Dataset is Stated below

[image: Dataframe]

My query is to Extract those rows which contain Multiple input words(Multiple Strings) that are entered by the user.

PFB, example for a Single String

[image: Single String]

I used the below code for Multiple Strings with LOGICAL "OR" operator using '|'.

[image: Multi String]

My Main Query is to Find the words with **"AND"** Operator.
I want to search for rows containing **["Product", "Jumbo", "Peanut"]** and only the 6th row satisfies it, So is there any logic like the above to show the rows containing the search inputs.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/470602/3832970

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas dataframe str.contains() AND operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex expression:

```
print(df[df['Text'].str.contains(r'(?=.*Product)(?=.*Jumbo)(?=.*Peanut)')])
```