# How to test if a string contains all of the substrings in a list: pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pd series that contains

```
s = pd.Series(['cat, pet','dog, pet','dog','bird', 'bird, pet','tail', 'cat, tail'])
```

and I want to find all places where `s` contains both of `['cat', 'pet']`

I know that I want to find `'cat'` *OR* `'pet'`, so I just filter like:

```
 search = ['cat', 'pet']
 s[s.str.contains('|'.join(search))]
```

But what if I want to match `'cat'` *AND* `'pet'`??

I tried:

```
s[s.str.contains('&'.join(search))]
```

But it is not working for me :/

Comment: you will find what you are looking for here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: We have got to be careful here. When searching substrings in a string or conglomeration of strings we use regex and not normal language phrases. regex ( rational expression) is a sequence of characters not words in a search pattern. What you want therefore can be achieved by wrapping the two words in a regex `(character1).*(character2)|(character2).*(character1)`. 

`.` any character ;`*` zero or n occurrences of the preceding regex

In your case `s.str.contains('(cat).*(pet)|(pet).*(cat)')`

Comment: I will reformulate the question because df[(df['col_name'].str.contains('apple')) & (df['col_name'].str.contains('banana'))]
 That is a valid answer, does not actually answer my question, because It does not contemplate the case when len(list_of_strings) is variable or has as size < 100 which is my real case