# search for a partial string from list and add column with that parital str

Tags: python, pandas

I wont to search a df.column for a partial strings that I saved in a series and wont to create a new column with the str that I found in each row. A part of my  question was solved by 
[pandas: test if string contains one of the substrings in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/pandas-test-if-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list):

> For example, say I have the series s = pd.Series(['cat','hat','dog','fog','pet']), and I want to find all places where s contains any of ['og', 'at'], I would want to get everything but pet.

The solution is:

```
>>> searchfor = ['og', 'at']
>>> s[s.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
0    cat
1    hat
2    dog
3    fog
dtype: object
```

but I would like to get

```
         pet    contains
    0    cat    at
    1    hat    at
    2    dog    og
    3    fog    og
    dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and if no match get `NaN`s, so add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
searchfor = ['og', 'at']
df['new'] = df['pet'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(searchfor) + ')', expand=False)
df = df.dropna(subset=['new'])
print (df)
   pet contains1 new
0  cat        at  at
1  hat        at  at
2  dog        og  og
3  fog        og  og
```