# Check if a string contains one or more of list values in python

Tags: python

I have a list and a string as follows.

```
mylist = ["tim tam", "yogurt", "strawberry"]
mystring = "I love to eat tim tam"
```

Now I want to check if `mystring` contains one or more words in `mylist`. If it contains the `flag` variable should be true, if not false.

My current code is as follows.

```
if mylist in mystring:
    flag = 1
else:
    flag = 0
```

However, I get the error `TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable`. Not sure why it happens. Please help me.

Comment: This is inefficient, but `int(any(x in mystring for x in my list))`

Comment: If you get that exception, then `mystring` is _not_ what you think it is, but a method.

Comment: See these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas/60980656#60980656

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression in `any` to check each substring against your original string

```
>>> flag = any(i in mystring for i in mylist)
>>> flag
True
```

If you want an `int` instead of a `bool` you can modify the above to

```
>>> flag = int(any(i in mystring for i in mylist))
>>> flag
1
```

Comment: You can add that `all` and `any` are short circuiting in Python and this behavior is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.contains- or lambda-function for filtering (I use it for DataFrame).

```
df=df.str.contains("keyword1|keyword2|keyword3", na=False)]
```

or

```
ddf[df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('keyword1|keyword2|keyword3', case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

Example:

```
mylist = 'tim tam|yogurt|strawberry'   
df = pd.DataFrame(df[df[[0,1,2,3...]].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains(mylist, case=False).any(), axis=1)])
```

Comment: Huh... where has pandas come from?