# Search and return index of matching substring with pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I want to extend the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/pandas-test-if-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list#_=_)

The solutions in the above question return True or False. And the boolean values can be used to subset the right values.

However, I want to get the search value that matched a substring.

For example,(borrowing from the above question)

```
s = pd.Series(['cat','hat','dog','fog','pet'])
searchfor = ['og', 'at']
```

I want to know that 'cat' matched with 'at' and dog matched with 'og'

Comment: Feel free to upvote your chosen answer as well. Thanks (-:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you want the values to reflect the *index* of the item in the `searchfor` list that matched your word. You can start by modifying your `searchfor` object -

```
m = {'^.*{}.*$'.format(s) : str(i) for i, s in enumerate(searchfor)}
```

This is a dictionary of `<pattern : index>` mappings. Now, call `pd.Series.replace` with `regex=True` -

```
s = s.replace(m, regex=True)
s[:] = np.where(s.str.isdigit(), pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce'), -1)
```

```
s

0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
4   -1
dtype: int64
```

---

If you want a list of matched values by pattern, you'll need `str.extract` + `groupby` + `apply` -

```
p = '(^.*({}).*$)'.format('|'.join(searchfor))

s.str.extract(p, expand=True)\
 .groupby([1])[0]\
 .apply(list)

1
at    [cat, hat]
og    [dog, fog]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I realized what I actually want is to return all the matched strings as comma separated values. I will ask another question for it.

Comment: @SharvariGc No, don't worry about it. I'll edit my answer. Edit: Done, see my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks. How would I get ['og,at']  for the first element of the series, s = pandas.Series(['cat dog','hat cat','dog','fog cat','pet']) while searching for 
searchfor = ['og', 'at']

Comment: It is really hard think outside the np.where :-)

Comment: @SharvariGc Ah... that's quite hard. Can you open another q?

Comment: asked here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615699/pandas-return-all-matched-keys-for-each-strings-value-in-a-series) @COLDSPEED

Answer (score 2):

This is by using `defaultdict` + `replace` finally I made it ..

```
d=dict(zip(searchfor,[""]*2))

s1=s.replace(d,regex=True)
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for x,y in zip(s1.index,s1):
    d[x][y]=''

s.to_frame('a').T.replace(dict(d), regex=True).T.a


Out[765]: 
0    at
1    at
2    og
3    og
4      
Name: a, dtype: object
```