# pandas: return all matched keys for each strings value in a series

Tags: regex, pandas, series

How to return all the matched keys of from a search list as comma-separated values.

For example,

```
s = pd.Series(['cat dog','hat cat','dog','fog cat','pet'])
searchfor = ['cat', 'dog']
```

I want to get this:

> ['cat, dog',  'cat',  'dog',  'cat',  'None']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague helped me with it.
Here is how I finally did it:

```
s = pandas.Series(['cat dog','hat cat','dog','fog cat','pet'])
searchfor = ['cat', 'dog']

b = ['']*len(s)
for i in numpy.arange(0,len(s)):
    for j in numpy.arange(0,len(searchfor)):
        b[i] = b[i] + ', ' + searchfor[j] if searchfor[j] in s[i] and b[i]!= '' else (searchfor[j] if searchfor[j] in s[i] else b[i])
df = DataFrame({'s': s, 'searchfor': [numpy.nan if i=='' else i for i in b]})
```

df

```
    s        searchfor
0   cat dog  cat, dog
1   hat cat  cat
2   dog      dog
3   fog cat  cat
4   pet      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `split` it 1st then doing `str.contains`

```
s1=s.str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()

s1[s1.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))].groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join).reindex(s.index)
Out[778]: 
0    cat dog
1        cat
2        dog
3        cat
4        NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. That Worked!

Comment: @SharvariGc if it is what you need can you accept it?

Comment: I just realized that it is picking up values from string s for the output, however, I want the values to be picked up from the list search for in the output column and return as comma separated values. And also give uniques, for example it should not return cat, cat

Comment: attempt to notify u about the above comment.