# Returning a list entry after a substring search using list of substrings

Tags: python, arrays, string, substring

This question slightly branches off of these two topics:

[How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list)

[Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/check-if-a-python-list-item-contains-a-string-inside-another-string/52014148#52014148)

Because while it's very closely related, it doesn't really seem to give me the answer i need. I've tried to reverse engineer what I've been reading to no success. so here goes:

what If I wanted to print out the member of the "matchers" list, how do I go about it? :/

```
myObjs = ['R_obj', 'objectLeft']
sideNames = ['L_','R_', '_L', '_R', 'Right', 'Left', 'right', 'left']

for i in myObjs:
    xx = [side in i for side in sideNames]
    if any (xx):
        print "something is found in " + i

    # ================= other attempts at printing:  =================
    #   print [side in i for side in sideNames] <-- gives list of booleans.
    #   print xx
    #   print str(sideNames[side]) + "found is in " + i
    #   print sideNames.side
    #   print side
    # ================= other attempts at printing:  =================
```

Basically I'm trying to print the sideNames ***list member*** in place of "something", but my different attempts have all been giving me wrong syntaxes :/

PS: I have a feeling that im using [] and () incorrectly

Comment: So you want outputs like `R_ is found in R_obj`?

Comment: Yes thank you. Thats exactly what im looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myObjs = ['R_obj', 'objectLeft']
sideNames = ['L_','R_', '_L', '_R', 'Right', 'Left', 'right', 'left']

for i in myObjs:
    for side in sideNames:
        if side in i:
            print side, "is found in ", i
```

will give the result:

```
R_ is found in  R_obj
Left is found in  objectLeft
```