# Extarct Rows Until a Certain Row with Certain Word of a Column Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
   Name    Product    Quantity
0  NaN     1010       10
1  NaN     2010       12
2  NaN     4145       18
3  NaN     5225       14
4  Total   6223       16
5  RRA     7222       18
6  MLQ     5648       45
```

Now, I need to extract rows/new dataframe that has rows until `Total` that is in `Name` column.

Output needed:

```
       Name    Product    Quantity
    0  NaN     1010       10
    1  NaN     2010       12
    2  NaN     4145       18
    3  NaN     5225       14
```

I tried this,

```
df[df.Name.str.contains("Total", na=False)]
```

This is not helpful for now. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the index where the `True` value is located and slice using [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df_new=df.iloc[:df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('Total',na=False)].index[0]]
```

or using [`series.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) which allows you to get the  index of max value (max of True/False is True):

```
df_new=df.iloc[:df.Name.str.contains('Total',na=False).idxmax()]

print(df_new)

  Name  Product  Quantity
0  NaN     1010        10
1  NaN     2010        12
2  NaN     4145        18
3  NaN     5225        14
```

Comment: a follow up question, if I have to use an `or` operation, let say I want to extract row until `Total` or `Subtotal` how can I do that? If I have to do for a list of files and that has different key words that I need to extract until, then it can be helpful. Any ideas?

Comment: @user9431057 check this it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list