# how to filter single column(dtype=object) in pandas on mutliple values

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and iam trying to filter columns(dtype=object) based pandas str.contains or startswith. However when i run the code iam getting first argument must be string or compiled pattern error. how to resolve it.

df_ipp_h_simple_hsr = df_ipp_h_simple[df_ipp_h_simple['ORDER_TYPE'].str.startswith(('HSR', 'HOSP')) &
                                       df_ipp_h_simple['PRODUCT'].str.contains("M") &
                                      ~df_ipp_h_simple['PRODUCT'].str.contains(("1611","1612","1635")) &
                                      ~df_ipp_h_simple['PRODUCT'].str.startswith(("5","6","97")) &
                                      ~df_ipp_h_simple['CUSTOMER'].str.contains(("POPEYES","CHECKERS","KRYSTAL"))
                                     ]

expected output is filtered dataframe but iam getting below error:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\enzy\lib\re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    283         return pattern
    284     if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
--> 285         raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
    286     p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    287     if not (flags & DEBUG):

TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.Series.str.contains` does not accept a tuple of strings as first argument (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains). However, you try to do it in these two lines:

```
~df_ipp_h_simple['PRODUCT'].str.contains(("1611","1612","1635")) 
~df_ipp_h_simple['CUSTOMER'].str.contains(("POPEYES","CHECKERS","KRYSTAL"))
```

The error tells you that it needs a string or a compiled regex.

You should use a regular expression for a search with multiple patterns like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577689/9144990