# How to drop rows in pandas data frame if one column contains certain values in a specified list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame **new** and want to drop rows if the column **Name** contains certain values specified in a list **lst**.

Original DF:

```
        Name         
0  Jack Wang 
1  Jack Lee 
2  Mabel Smith
3  Amber Golden

lst = ['Wang', 'Smith']
```

Desired DF:

```
        Name   
1  Jack Lee
2  Amber Golden
```

Below is my code:

```
for i in range(len(new)):
    if any(elem in lst for elem in new['Name'][i].split()) == True:
        new2 = new.drop([i])
```

However, it could identify rows with **Name** column containing values in **lst**, but the rows could not be dropped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `new.loc[~new['Name'].isin(lst)]` ? please share sample data, as well as desired output

Comment: Your issue is that `new2` only reflects changes on the last iteration. Each iteration refers to the original `new`. Dropping on the fly like this changes the shape of the dataframe anyway so is not the best approach. @politicalscientist shows a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I edited my question with the original dataset and desired outcome, basically I want to remove the rows that have Name values containing values in lst after split Name values. Could you please suggest? Thanks

Comment: @MAMS, thanks for the update. Now I see that `isin` wouldn't work in this case. instead, try `new.loc[new['Name'].str.contains('|'.join(lst))]`

Comment: If you want to learn more, check out: [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577689/10140310)