# Pandas, finding match(any) between list of strings and df column values(as list) to create new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings. I need to iterate through rows of my dataframe to try to find if any or more of list items are included in value of one column(string). I'm trying to find substring match between any list item and dataframe column value. Then, I need to assign matched value(s) to a new column or pass NaN if there's no match. Not just any, but all matched parts of string. So, in the third row of my df, these would be both 'E' and 'F22'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['A23 E I28','I28 F A23', 'D41 E F22']})
matches = ['E', 'F22']
```

Comment: have a look: [How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577689/10140310)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

If there's a match, the keyword is assigned to a new colum

```py
df['new_col'] = df['type'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(matches)})")
```

```
    type        new_col
0   A23 E I28   E
1   I28 F A23   NaN
2   D41 E F22   E
```

---

Edit:

```py
df['new_col'] = (df['type']
                 .str.findall(f"({'|'.join(matches)})")
                 .str.join(', ')
                 .replace('', np.nan))
```

```py
    type    new_col
0   A23 E I28   E
1   I28 F A23   NaN
2   D41 E F22   E, F22
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I pass all matched substrings, not just any? (both 'E' and 'F22' for third row)

Comment: I just want to pass the matched parts of row value (substrings). In third row of the df these would be 'E' and 'F22', because both of them are in my matches list.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
df["match"] = df.type.map(lambda s: "".join(set(s).intersection(matches)))  
df.loc[~df.type.str.contains("|".join(matches)), "match"] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a similar result. What I need is to pass matched substrings to a new 'match' column, but I'm unable to do this.

Comment: Close, but please read my explanation at the end of the post(description) once again. :)