# Search in column a list of word and create a boolean column if a word is found

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

Hello problem to loop over a column by searching a list of word then create a Boolean column if any of the list word searched is found.
Here is my code

```
# Code naf related to sport.
code = ["3230Z","4764Z","7721Z","8551Z","9311Z", "9312Z", "9313Z", "9319Z",
        "9329Z", "364Z" "524W", "714B", "804C", "926A", "926C", "930L", "927C",
        "923K"]

# check keywords of code into "Code_Naf" column
for branch in code:
    df_codeNaf["topNAF"] = df_codeNaf["Code_NAF"].str.contains("3230Z" or "4764Z" or "7721Z" or "8551Z"
                                                                      or "9311Z" or "9312Z" or "9313Z" or "9319Z"
                                                                      or "9329Z" or "364Z" "524W" or "714B" or
                                                                      "804C" or "926A" or "926C" or "930L" or
                                                                      "927C" or "923K")
```

When I look in the topNaf column I found only 2 True but in reality there more than two. What's wrong with my code?
Thanks

Comment: `"xxx" or "yyy"` isn't doing what you think it does

Comment: First i suggest you to remove the huge "contains". It should exist another method to check if is in list...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas

Comment: Further reading: [Strange use of “and” / “or” operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-and-or-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a method using lambda

```
code = ["3230Z","4764Z","7721Z","8551Z","9311Z", "9312Z", "9313Z", "9319Z",
        "9329Z", "364Z" "524W", "714B", "804C", "926A", "926C", "930L", "927C",
        "923K"]

df_codeNaf["topNAF"] = df_codeNaf["Code_NAF"].apply(lambda x: True if x in code else False)
```

Comment: `apply` is slow and inefficient - since `str.contains` can do the same job, it would be much more recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you change `df_codeNaf['topNAF']` with every single `banch` in `code`. You code can be fixed by:

```
df_codeNaf['topNAF'] = False
for branch in code:
    df_codeNaf['topNAF'] = df_codeNaf['topNAF'] | df_codeNaf['Code_NAF'].str.contains(branch).
```

But better yet, you can try `regex` with `contains` in one line:

```
pattern = '|'.join(code)
df_codeNaf['topNAF'] = df_codeNaf['Code_NAF'].str.contains(pattern)
```

Comment: Hello, this lead also to 2 (True) as my code result.