# Python: How do I create a new variable which is a boolean indicator of another variable's value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
DayDate   Value
19-01-01  500
19-01-02  750
19-01-03  1000
```

And I want to create this data:

```
DayDate Value  IsAboveMedian
19-01-01  500    False
19-01-02  750    False
19-01-03  1000   True
```

How do I do that in Python, add a Boolean that is a calculation of another variable?

Comment: hint: `df['Value'].median` gives you the median, and then you can use that to compare.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  Anytime you add or delete a row, or update the `Value` of an existing row, the median will likely change.  So now you have to go back and recalculate all the `IsAboveMedian` values.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need:

```
df['IsAboveMedian'] = df['Value']>df['Value'].median()
```

Output:

```
DayDate Value  IsAboveMedian
19-01-01  500    False
19-01-02  750    False
19-01-03  1000   True
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried something similar but I failed, then I realized that the table I was working with had a multiindex.

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with index. Not sure what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this could help you. Check before posting question because this is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890838/8333806) .

```
l = [2,58,8,69,9,7]
df  = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['values'])
np.median(df['values'])

df["IsAboveMedian"] = df["values"].apply(lambda x: True if x>np.median(df['values']) else False)
```

Comment: `True if x > np.median(...) else False` is redundant