# How can I remove a substring from a given String using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, substring, contains

Recently I started to analyse a data frame and I want to remove all the substrings that don't contain

```
('Aparelho Celular','Internet (Serviços e Produtos)','Serviços Telefônicos Diversos','Telefonia Celular','Telefonia Comunitária ( PABX, DDR, Etc. )','Telefonia Fixa','TV por Assinatura','Televisão / Aparelho DVD / Filmadora','Telemarketing')
```

But when I use this syntax-

```py
df = df[~df["GrupoAssunto"].str.contains('Aparelho Celular','Internet (Serviços e Produtos)','Serviços Telefônicos Diversos','Telefonia Celular','Telefonia Comunitária ( PABX, DDR, Etc. )','Telefonia Fixa','TV por Assinatura','Televisão / Aparelho DVD / Filmadora','Telemarketing')]
```

I get this error:

```py
TypeError: contains() takes from 2 to 6 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataframe and expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas)

Comment: Please update the question to clarify the use-case, along with a sample of the dataset and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.isin()` function instead.

For example:

```
vals1 = ['good val1', 'good val2', 'good val3', 'Aparelho Celular','Internet (Serviços e Produtos)','Serviços Telefônicos Diversos','Telefonia Celular','Telefonia Comunitária ( PABX, DDR, Etc. )','Telefonia Fixa','TV por Assinatura','Televisão / Aparelho DVD / Filmadora','Telemarketing']
vals2 = ['Aparelho Celular','Internet (Serviços e Produtos)','Serviços Telefônicos Diversos','Telefonia Celular','Telefonia Comunitária ( PABX, DDR, Etc. )','Telefonia Fixa','TV por Assinatura','Televisão / Aparelho DVD / Filmadora','Telemarketing']

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': vals1})
```

Using the negated `.isin()` function will provide a view on the DataFrame excluding the values in the `vals2` list.:

```
df[~df['col1'].isin(vals2)]
```

Output:

```
        col1
0  good val1
1  good val2
2  good val3
```

Comment: This accomplishes something else. `isin()` doesn't work for substrings in the same way as `str.contains`. The OP's issue seems to just be syntax based

Comment: @noah - Ok, fair enough.  OP needs to update the question to be more explicit, and provide a use-case.  (Commented accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

Just seperate the different words by `|` with regex turned on. This is the proper syntax for searching for multiple strings with contains. The `re` safe conversion deals with escaping the parenthesis and any other special characters.

```
bad_strings = ['Aparelho Celular','Internet (Serviços e Produtos)','Serviços Telefônicos Diversos','Telefonia Celular','Telefonia Comunitária ( PABX, DDR, Etc. )','Telefonia Fixa','TV por Assinatura','Televisão / Aparelho DVD / Filmadora','Telemarketing']
safe_bad_strings = [re.escape(s) for s in bad_strings]
df = df[~df["GrupoAssunto"].str.contains('|'.join(safe_bad_strings), regex=True]
```

Your error is occurring because the 10 strings are all being passed as arguments to contains. But contains doesn't expect more than one pattern so it is throwing an error.