# Multiple groupings and aggregations within one dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to:

filter the values in the 'id' column, group these values, take their average, and then sum these values

```
  id    use free    total   G_Used  G_Free  G_Total
   a    5   5       10      4       1       5
   b    14  6       20      5       1       6
   a    10  5       15      9       1       10
   c    6   4       10      10      10      20
   b    10  5       15      5       5       10
   b    5   5       10      1       4       5
   c    4   1       5       3       1       4
```

**Desired Output**

```
use   free  total   
9.5   7.5   20
```

- filter only values that contain 'a' or 'b'
- group by each id
- take the mean of the 'use', 'free' and 'total' columns
- sum these values

**Intermediate steps:**

*filter out only the a and  c values*

```
id  use free    total   G_Used  G_Free  G_Total
a   5   5       10      4       1       5
a   10  5       15      9       1       10
c   6   4       10      10      10      20
c   4   1       5       3       1       4
```

*take mean of a*

```
a   
    
use free    total   
7.5 5       12.5
```

*take mean of c*

c

```
use free    total   
2   2.5     7.5
```

*sum both a and c values* for final desired output

```
use free    total   
9.5 7.5     20
```

This is what I am doing, however the syntax is not correct for some of the code. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated

```
df1 = df[df.id = 'a' | 'b']
df2 = df1.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).agg({'use': 'mean', 'free': 'mean', 'total': 'mean'})
df3= df2.sum(['id'], axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership first and then filter columns with `mean`, ouput is summed and converted Series to one row DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for transpose:

```
df1 = df[df.id.isin(['a','c'])]
df2 = df1.groupby('id')[['use','free','total']].mean().sum().to_frame().T
```

Your solution is similar, only used [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df[df.id.isin(['a','c'])]
df2 = df1.groupby('id').agg({'use': 'mean', 'free': 'mean', 'total': 'mean'}).sum().to_frame().T
```

---

```
print (df2)
    use  free  total
0  12.5   7.5   20.0
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael, what if I have a scenario where I wish to filter if the value CONTAINS a certain word , or IS LIKE- is there something like this? I am researching- thank you

Comment: @Lynnette - yes, then use instead `isin` this solution - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577689)

Comment: @Lynnette - So here `df1 = df[df.id.str.contains('|'.join(['a','c']))]`

Comment: Hi @Jezrael - thank you- I think my data contains NaN -It gives me this error: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values - Is there a way around this? Thank you

Comment: @Lynnette Use `df1 = df[df.id.str.contains('|'.join(['a','c']), na=False)]`