# Pandas if column contains any of the keyword in a list. Then how can I check which keyword(s) are found?

Tags: python, pandas

[How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas)

In the link above, many people suggested the chosen answer, which is...

```
searchfor = ['og', 'at']
s[s.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

In my case, I have 300+ searchfor in the list. and I also have several thousand rows in s.
Using the way above, I can quickly check if any of the keyword is in the column. However, I am not sure how to create another column in s that shows what searchfor words are in the column.

For example, if

```
s.loc[0,'fulltext'] = 'ff og at ew'
```

, then

```
s.loc[0, 'found_keyword'] = ['og, 'at']
```

if

```
s.loc[1, 'fulltext'] = 'ff og ew gg'
```

, then

```
s.loc[1, 'found_keyword'] = ['og']
```

Any recommendation will be very appreciated.

Comment: one solution in mind is to use `applymap` and`lambda` or `.iterrows` and go through each row i guess...

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.extractall`:

```
df['found_keyword'] = (df['fulltext'].str.extractall(f'({pattern})')
                           .groupby(level=0)[0].agg(list)
                      )
```

Output:

```
      fulltext found_keyword
0  ff og at ew      [og, at]
1  ff og ew gg          [og]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I just tried but I have some issues. My patterns are something like ['Arizona', 'Florida', 'Cleveland', ...] which are the state names. When I run the code, a cell of 'Florida USA' becomes [F, l, o, r, i, d, a, , U, S, A]. It seems it just breaks down the fulltext into each character. Am I using it in a wrong way.