# Pandas: Filter to get rows which contain a character not on a specified list

Tags: python, pandas

Say this is my column (datatype is string)

```
'83.83'
'334-339.99'
'45'
'(34.23)'
'R34.2'
```

I would like to filter so that only rows which contain a character that  is not on this list

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'R', '.']
```

So I would only get these rows

```
'334-339.99'
'(34.23)'
```

I have been able to look up methods to specifically include or exclude certain characters and substrings in pandas

[How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas)

Which I don't  think applies to my situation. If I filter for all the characters on the list, I get all the rows in my example. If I filter out for those characters, then I get no rows from my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
out = s[s.apply(lambda x : any([item not in r for item in x ]))]
Out[356]: 
1    334-339.99
3       (34.23)
dtype: object
```

Where r is the list of characters/substrings