# Assigning a value to a pandas column by Iterating through lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a three-part question - I have three lists and I'm trying to write a loop to iterate over either two of lists to assign a value to a new column based on a match (or through the list of lists). When I assign it to the column like below it only prints the else value or whatever number in the last condition. Thank you in advance.

1. Why is that?
2. How do I format this loop?
3. Can someone write a better for loop that iterates over `all_names` assigning 1 to a match from `all_names[0]` and 2 for a match `all_names[1]`? - does enumerate work for that?

   ```
   first_names = ['David', 'Dani', 'Declan']
   second_names = ['Katz', 'Foley', 'Stevenson']
   all_names = [first_names, second_names]

   for row in df['name']:
       for elem in firstname_list:
          if elem in row:
             df['name_num']= 1
       for elem in secondname_list:
          if elem in row:
             df['name_num']= 2
       else:
            df['name_num']= 3
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `np.select`:

```
df['name_num'] = np.select( (df['name'].isin(first_names), 
                             df['name'].isin(second_names) ),
                            (1,2), 3)
```

Comment: Im think something like this  for elem_a in first_name, for elem_b in second_name if elem_a is in row df[name_num] = 1 if elem_b is in row df[name_num] =2

Comment: Okay @Quang Ill try that in a minute, thanks!

Comment: is it possible to modify this to provide a match based on a partial match? e.g. I have Dani but would like it to match Danielle also

Comment: Replace `isin` with answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas).

Comment: Ahh I had tried with just .str.contains but not the |.join(list) thank you very much sir.