# Write a function that returns the count of the unique answers to all of the questions in a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

For example, after filtering the entire dataset to only questions containing the word "King", we could then find all of the unique answers to those questions.

I filtered by using the following code:

```
`def lower1(x):
   x.lower()

 filter_dataset = lambda x:all(x) in jeopardy.Question.apply(lower1) 
 print(filter_dataset(['King','England']))`
```

The above code is printing `True` instead of printing the rows of jeopardy['Question'] with the keywords 'King' and 'England'.

That is the first problem.

Now I want to count the unique answers to the jeopardy['Question']

Here is the sample data frame
[image]

Now I want to create a function that does the count of the unique answers.
I wrote the following code:

```
  `def unique_counts():
      print(jeopardy['Answer'].unique().value_counts())
   unique_counts()`
```

Which is giving me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: What do you mean by failed??

Comment: Added better dupe for check by substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
jeopardy[jeopardy['Question'].str.contains('|'.join(['King','England']))]
```

Comment: Answer was closed.

Comment: Let's wait for OP to comeback if this is what he wants. If he wants something else, question might need to be reopened.

Comment: I don't know why but the question was closed.

Comment: @KarthikBhandary - Is `isin` what need ? Or something else?

Comment: I am saying that I want to create a dataset out of the `jeopardy.Question` I used the `isin` but it created an empty dataset.

Comment: Hey @KarthikBhandary. Please share some sample dataframe with expected output in your question. This would help us understand it better and answer.

Comment: I added the data frame and edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: @KarthikBhandary Check my updated answer. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It is printing the `Answer` column I want the `Question` column as well

Comment: It will get you all the columns of the dataframe. Is `Question` column not printed?

Comment: Not sure. OP has not confirmed back. You have anyway closed the question as dupe. Let it be. I'll update you if it needs to be re-opened.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - yes, after more clear added new [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26578218/2901002). So accepting means dupe, if need OP something else, please reopen.

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks.

Comment: It was only printing the Answer column