# How to drop certain rows from dataframe if they partially meet certain condition

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, drop

I'm trying to drop rows from dataframe if they 'partially' meet certain condition.

By 'partially' I mean some (not all) values in the cell meet the condition.

Lets' say that I have this dataframe.

```
>>> df    
    Title                                  Body
0   Monday report: Stock market            You should consider buying this.
1   Tuesday report: Equity                 XX happened. 
2   Corrections and clarifications         I'm sorry.
3   Today's top news                       Yes, it skyrocketed as I predicted.
```

I want to remove the entire row if the Title has "Monday report:" or "Tuesday report:".

One thing to note is that I used

```
TITLE = []
.... several lines of codes to crawl the titles.
TITLE.append(headline)
```

to crawl and store them into dataframe.

Another thing is that my data are in tuples because I used

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(TITLE, BODY)), columns =['Title', 'Body'])
```

to make the dataframe.

I think that's why when I used,

```
df.query("'Title'.str.contains('Monday report:')")
```

I got an error.

When I did some googling here in StackOverflow, some advised to convert tuples into multi-index and to use `filter()`, `drop()`, or `isin()`.

None of them worked.

Or maybe I used them in a wrong way...?

Any idea to solve this prob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a basic filter for a condition and then pick reverse of it using `~`:

eg:
`df[~df['Title'].str.contains('Monday report')]` will give you output that excludes all rows that contain 'Monday report' in title.

Comment: Until now, I thought I got the error because my dataframe were not in string, because it said "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'". So I gave up using str.contains and also '~'. But your code works magically! Thanks!

Comment: How can I use multiple conditions in one line code? For example, `df[~df['Title'].str.contains('Monday report', 'Tuesday report', 'Corrections')]` ?

Comment: try using '|' if it's basic text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas/26578218