# Get all rows that have a column "Message" where at least one of the words is in Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

Consider the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('...csv')
array = [.....,....,....]
results = df[df.Message.isin(array).fillna(False)]
```

The column `Message` contains more than one word.

How can we get all rows that have the column "Message" where at least one of the words in `Message` is in the `array` ?

Example:

```
Client  Message                             City      Phone 
 
Jackson I will back soon                    Rome      1111
Cole    Please try to be patient            Cairo     2222 
Rains   Sure anything you want , anything   Paris     3333  

Array = ['try', 'anything', 'patient']
```

**Result**:

```
Cole    Please try to be patient            Cairo     2222 
Rains   Sure anything you want , anything   Paris     3333
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to include a few rows of the sample data?

Comment: So one cell in the Message column contains a list of one or more words?

Comment: @DSteman: Please see example.

Comment: @AnimikhAich: Attached :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

def generate_sample_data(words_to_be_detected):
  ## Generate Random words
  num_random_words = 20
  random_words = [''.join(np.random.choice(letters, np.random.randint(2,5)))
                  for _ in range(np.random.randint(num_random_words))] 

  ## Combine lists
  list_of_possible_words = random_words + words_to_be_detected

  ## define number of rows to be generated
  df_num_rows = 5

  ## Generate sample data
  data_sample_dict = [
      {"Message": list(np.random.choice(list_of_possible_words, np.random.randint(0,5)))}
      for _ in range(df_num_rows)         
  ]

  return pd.DataFrame(data_sample_dict)


## Define words to be found at Series
words_to_be_detected = ['XXXX', 'YYYY']

## Generate Synthetic Data
df = generate_sample_data(words_to_be_detected)

contains_str_mask = df.Message.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(words_to_be_detected))

display(df)

print('only the ones we are looking fore')
display(df[contains_str_mask])
```

the summary is:

`df.Message.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(words_to_be_detected))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (in a single line without loops):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Client','Message','City','Phone'],
['Jackson','I will back soon','Rome',1111],
['Cole','Please try to be patient','Cairo',2222 ],
['Rains','Sure anything you want , anything','Paris',3333  ]]

Array = ['try', 'anything', 'patient']

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

print (df[df['Message'].str.contains('|'.join(Array))])
```

Inspired by [How to test if a string contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas) and [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would solve your problem:

```py
Array = ['try', 'anything', 'patient']

def find_words(element):
     for word in Array:
         if word in element:
             return True
     return False

results = df[df["Message"].apply(find_words)]
```

**Edit:**

In addition to the above, we can also pull it off with a one-liner. This is not an elegant solution, But it works :)

```py
Array = ['try', 'anything', 'patient']

results = df[df["Message"].apply(lambda x: True if word in x else False for word in Array).any(1)]
```