# Add a new column with matching values in a list in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
the_list =['LjHH','Lhy_kd','Ljk']

COL1 COL2 
A    ADJJDUD878_Lhy_kd
B    Y0_0099JJ_Ljk
C    YTUUDBBDHHD
D    POL0990E_LjHH'
```

And I would like to add a new `COL3` column where if within `COL2` I have a match with a value in `the_list`, I add in that column the matching element of `the_list`.

Expected result;

```
COL1 COL2               COL3
A    ADJJDUD878_Lhy_kd  Lhy_kd
B    Y0_0099JJ_2_Ljk    Ljk    
C    YTUUDBBDHHD        NA
D    POL0990E_LjHH'     LjHH
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter pandas DataFrame by substring criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria)

Comment: I think [```this```](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577516/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-one-of-the-substrings-in-a-list-in-pandas) link can be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

For get only first matched values use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with joined values of lists by `|` for regex `or`:

```
the_list =['LjHH','Lhy_kd','Ljk']

df['COL3'] = df['COL2'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(the_list)})', expand=False)
print (df)
  COL1               COL2    COL3
0    A  ADJJDUD878_Lhy_kd  Lhy_kd
1    B      Y0_0099JJ_Ljk     Ljk
2    C        YTUUDBBDHHD     NaN
3    D     POL0990E_LjHH'    LjHH
```

For get all matched values (if possible multiple values) use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and last repalce empty string to `NaN`s:

```
the_list =['LjHH','Lhy_kd','Ljk']

df['COL3']=df['COL2'].str.findall(f'{"|".join(the_list)}').str.join(',').replace('',np.nan)
print (df)
  COL1               COL2    COL3
0    A  ADJJDUD878_Lhy_kd  Lhy_kd
1    B      Y0_0099JJ_Ljk     Ljk
2    C        YTUUDBBDHHD     NaN
3    D     POL0990E_LjHH'    LjHH
```