# Regex with Replace String Python

Tags: regex, string, replace, backslash

I have this situation, I have a sentence with wrong dot (.) to process, the sentence:

```
sentence = 'Hi. Long time no see .how are you ?can you follow .@abcde?'
```

I am trying to normalize this sentence, if you see it, there is some wrong format sentence (.how, ?can, and .@abcde). I am thinking of using regex to handle this because the sentence keep changing. This is my code so far:
    import re

```
character = ['.','?','@']

sentence = 'Hi. Long time no see .how are you ?can you follow .@abcde?'

sentence = str(sentence)
for i in character:
    charac = str(i)
    charac_after = re.findall(r'\\'+charac+r'\S*', sentence)
    if charac_after:
        print("Exist")
        sentence = sentence.replace(charac, charac+' ')

print(sentence)
```

The result some how skip the dot (.) and at (@) it just process the question mark (?). This is the result:
Exist

```
Hi. Long time no see .how are you ? can you follow .@abcde?
```

its supposed to be "Hi. Long time no see . how are you ? can you follow . @ abcde?". I don't know if my double backslash in "r'\'+charac+r'\S*'" are wrong or something, did I miss something?

How can I process all the character? please help.

Comment: I do not know python but you probably need to escape correctly see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python

Comment: If `r'\\'` is supposed to escape the next character following you only need to use a single backslash. At the moment you are escaping the backslash. However you should use `re.escape` instead.

Comment: but i think your code is faulty anyway. you will add a space after every `.|?|@` with that

Comment: @Fallenhero its my aim, add space after .|?|@, and i have tried the re.escape in r'\\'+re.escape(charac)+r'\S*'. Still have the same result. thank by the way

Comment: @ytomo oh i thought you only wanted to add a space after those if there is none already.

Comment: @SebastianProske I have tried r'\\'+re.escape(charac)+r'\S*', still have the same result. Did I miss something?

Comment: @ytomo you will not need the `\\\` if you already escape it.

Comment: @Fallenhero yes, add space after .|?|@ if there is none space after it (.how, ?can, and .@abcde) to (. how, ? can, and . @ abcde)

Comment: @Fallenhero still need the double backslash, its error if it just '\', I am sorry if I get your idea the wrong way, still new in python.

Comment: @ytomo dont use any `\\` there

Comment: @ytomo `\S*` will match everything. You will need `\S+` or just `\S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowlegde of python i think you need to do it like this:

(as per suggestion from @Sebastian Proske)

```
character = ['.','?','@']
sentence = str('Hi. Long time no see .how are you ?can you follow .@abcde?')
sentence = re.sub(r'([' + ''.join(map(re.escape, character)) + r'])(?=\S)', r'\1 ', sentence)
print(sentence)
```

The code i am not sure about, but the regex. see here:
https://regex101.com/r/HXdeuK/2

see demo here https://repl.it/Fw5b/3

Comment: hi, thanks before, I get new error:
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern

Comment: will those characters change? or why dont you just use them directly in the regex, like i did on regex101

Comment: I got the backreference wrong, i updated it. Now it works perfectly

Comment: Why so complicated? `print(re.sub(r'([' + ''.join(map(re.escape, character)) + r'])(\S)', r'\1 \2', sentence))` - I don't see a need for that for loop.

Comment: sorry i dont know python and OP did it like this

Comment: hi @SebastianProske thanks, good references. first line `jmap = '['+''.join(character)+']'` and second `print(re.sub(r'('+jmap+r')(\S)', r"\1 \2", sentence))` actually work. but it miss the @abcde?, result: `Hi. Long time no see . how are you ? can you follow . @abcde?` that the loop get it perfectly. thanks

Comment: Oops, in `.@` the `@` is overlapping with the matched `\S`. Use a lookahed based solution then. `print(re.sub(r'([' + ''.join(map(re.escape, character)) + r'])(?=\S)', r'\1 ', sentence))`