# How to implement this in re.sub()?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings in **lst**

```
lst = ["-", "/", ","]
```

Examples for str to re.sub:

```
str = "abc - abc 9-4 "   => "abc abc 9-4 " 
str = "abc , abc 9/4 "   => "abc abc 9,4 " 
str = "abc / abc 9,4 "   => "abc abc 9/4 "
```

I want to replace all the matches for the given pattern with the string replace_with

I would like to implement it as follows

```
 new_str = re.sub(pattern,replace_with, str);
```

where,

```
replace_with = ""
pattern      =        Please help me define the following in regex
```

> (not number)(anything)(any of the strings in **lst**) (anything)(not
>   number)

Comment: [`(?<=\D)\s*[-/,](?=\s*\D)`](https://regex101.com/r/1VFEc2/1) or [`(?<!\d)\s*[-/,](?!\s*\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/1VFEc2/2) according to your specifications.

Comment: Don't complicate things! Seems like all you need is a neg. lookahead: [**`\s*[-,/](?!\d)`**](https://regex101.com/r/WzDvXv/2/)

Comment: @ctwheels  your answer will do the job for me except [-,/] . Because to read this from a list, as the strings I want to check changes in the run time.

Can you show how to do that with a list

Comment: @AthulMuralidharan just use the content from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python) post to escape the joined list. You should have something like `"(?<!\d)\s*[" + re.escape(lst.join()) + "](?!\s*\d)"` (note the actual code I just wrote might not work - I can't test it at the moment - but it will resemble this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lst = ["-", "/", ","]
import re
s = ["abc - abc 9-4 ", "abc , abc 9/4 ", "abc / abc 9,4 "]
final_data = [re.sub('\s|\s'.join(lst), ' ',  i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['abc  abc 9-4 ', 'abc  abc 9/4 ', 'abc abc 9,4 ']
```

Comment: This works great . This is the answer I was looking for. Because my lst is dynamic

Comment: @AthulMuralidharan glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it! Thank you!

Comment: My hard earned reputation has been brought down by some people. I don't know why  I am getting so many down votes for this question. I really think this is a valid question. Though I would like to accept your answer, i don't have the privilege to do that.

Comment: @AthulMuralidharan no problem!