# String Search with error "Unexpected End of Regular Expression"

Tags: python-2.7

I want to search string `a` in string `b = "sed s/xxx/[/"`

Code:

```
a = "data sed s/xxx/[/"
b = r'\ssed s/xxx/[/\b'
re.findall(b,a)
```

Output Error

```
unexpected end of regular expression.
```

Comment: If you are writing new Python code, you should definitely be targeting Python 3 now.

Comment: Already code is there in python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `[` is a regular-expression metacharacter. In order to match it literally, you need to escape it.

```
r'\ssed s/xxx/\[/'   # backslash-escape it, or
r'\ssed s/xxx/[[]/'  # put it in a character class
```

The second example also shows what the metacharacter is actually used for.  In regular expressions, `[abc]` matches a single character out of the enumeration (so either `a` or `b` or `c`); this is called a character class.

Comment: The above solution is working fine. how make generic patter to work for any string

Comment: It's unclear what you mean; are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import re

a = "data sed s/xxx/[/"
b = r'\ssed s/xxx/\[/'

print re.findall(b,a)
```

Comment: There is no need to escape the last slash. Slash doesn't have any special meaning in Python regular expressions (and if it did, you would have to escape all the slashes).

Comment: @tripleee; You are right I did not see that. Thanks.

Comment: The above solution is working fine. how make generic patter to work for any string