# Remove all slashes and backsleshes

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, char

I have a string:

```
res = 'qwer!@ 234234 4234gdf36/\////// // \ \\\$%^$% dsfg'
```

and I want to remove ALL slashes and backslashes.
I tried this:

```
import string
import re

symbolsToRemove = string.punctuation
res = 'qwer!@ 234234 4234gdf36/\////// // \ \\\$%^$% dsfg'
res = re.sub(r'['+symbolsToRemove+']', ' ', res)
print(res)
```

But get the next result:

> qwer   234234 4234gdf36 \          \ \      dsfg

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you not just do `res.replace ("\\", "").replace ("/", "")`

Comment: The resulting regex is `[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]` and the ``\`` escaspes a `]` in it. You should escape the symbols to match literal chars. Or at least escape the `-`, `]`, `^` and ``\``.

Comment: Replace works just fine. Don't bother with regular expressions.

Comment: @Mathieu i think we should encourage the use of regex, as they are fast and efficient

Comment: also related [escaping regex string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python) : `'[' + re.escape(symbolsToRemove) + ']'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with `re.escape`:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'['+re.escape(symbolsToRemove)+']+', ' ', res)
qwer  234234 4234gdf36        dsfg
```

Comment: Yes, it does: `>>> string.punctuation` `'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'`

Comment: Sorry for the goof up. Yes OP just needs to do `re.esacpe`

Comment: I didn't get it - you previous answer did it well :) What's the matter to change it?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam: Previous answer also worked because it had separate \\ but I had wrong explanation. This one will also work because `re.escape(symbolsToRemove)` will escape each and every special character in `symbolsToRemove` string where \ is already present.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
import re
symbolsToRemove = string.punctuation
res = 'qwer!@ 234234 4234gdf36/\////// // \ \\\$%^$% dsfg'
res = re.sub(r'[\\]*[\/]*','', res)
print(res)
```