# Escaping repl argument of re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I would like to make sure the `repl` argument of `re.sub` is escape, so that any special sequences like `\1` are not interpreted:

```
>>> repl = r'\1'
>>> re.sub('(X)', repl, 'X')
'X'
>>> re.sub('(X)', desired_escape_function(repl), 'X')
'\\1'
```

Is there a function that can do this? I know that [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) exists, should this be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `re.escape` for this purpose. `re.escape` is meant to be used in the `pattern` argument, not the `repl` argument.

Instead, follow [the advice of Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), and just replace all backslashes with two backslashes manually:

```
>>> repl = r'\1'
>>> re.sub('(X)', repl.replace('\\', '\\\\'), 'X')
'\\1'
```