# Regular expression to get substring from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

consider I have a string as following,

```
\n this is a paragraph. please ignore  \n this is a only for testing. please ignore \n
```

I have a search word as `"only for testing"`. and I want to get the sentence which contains `"only for testing"` with in the `\n` the search word resides.
In this case the output will be 
`this is a only for testing. please ignore`.

If I give `paragraph` as search word I should get the output as

```
this is a paragraph. please ignore
```

I have tried

```
test_str = "\\n this is a paragraph. please ignore  \\n this is a only for testing. please ignore \\n"
pattern = re.compile("\\\\n(.+?)\\\\n")
match = pattern.findall(test_str)
```

But not working as expected

Comment: `print ([sent for sent in test_str.split("\\n") if 'only for testing' in sent])` ([demo](https://rextester.com/RKBQ77131))

Comment: If you're insisting on a Regex solution then you need to escape your search term for use in regex and then interpolate that string within `(.+?)`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : How will I do that? I'm new to regex

Comment: You should Google the steps I mentioned individually. Here's a start, https://stackoverflow.com/q/280435/2191572. Are you new to Python too?

Comment: With regex, it will be a pain, see `re.findall(r'(?:^|\\n)((?:(?!\\n).)*only for testing(?:(?!\\n).)*)', test_str)` [demo](https://rextester.com/JISY46794)

Comment: Consider using raw strings (`r"foo"`) to prevent the blackslash plague. There is really no reason not to use raw strings when using regex with python.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Your first answer without using the regex should be good I guess. I will go for that. Thanks a lot Wiktor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a solution without a regular expression:

```
result = [sent for sent in test_str.split("\\n") if 'only for testing' in sent]
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/RKBQ77131)

**Details**

- `test_str.split("\\n")` - split the text by `\n`
- `if 'only for testing' in sent` - only keep the items that contain `only for testing` (for a case insensitive comparison, use `if 'only for testing' in sent.lower()`)