# Regular expression error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 108

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract words from **item_search** list. My regular expression works for normal words. However, it does not work for the words that contain unbalanced parenthesis.
Here is the code:

```
import re
strn = """
Hello every@one, I am trying@this code/module-but not work(ing properly)for 
unknown reason(s). It always stop with @regula-expression_error12
"""
item_search = ["Hello", "every@one","trying@this", "code/module-but", "work(ing properly)", "reason(s)", "@regula-expression_error12)"  ]
item=list(set(re.findall(rf"(?<!\S)({'|'.join(item_search)})\W*(?!\S)", strn, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)))
item
```

error:

```
error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 108
```

Looking for experts suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `re.escape`.  You are dynamically building a regular expression, but one of your components contains a character that is special to regexp.  You must quote that character for it to be used in a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but seems not working: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string). Would you please elaborate it with code.

Comment: Try replacing `item_search` with `re.escape(item_search)`.