# How to fix an error with unbalanced parenthesis at position x?

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook, python-regex

The following code gives me the error

> "unbalanced parenthesis at position 22"

This error is triggered at line `change = re.search(word[indice], contenu)` . I manage to remove the parentheses in the "contenu" variable but the error persists. Do you know what this could be due to?

```
import re
myTxt= open('MyFile.txt')
contenu = myTxt.read()
contenu = contenu.replace("\"","\\\"")
contenu = contenu.replace("\'", "\\\'")
contenu = contenu.replace(")", "")
contenu = contenu.replace("(", "")
for indice in range(0,len(word)):
    change = re.search(word[indice], contenu)
    if change != None:
        re.sub(word[indice], aRemplacer[indice], contenu)
        
myTxt.close()
```

"word" and "aRemplacer" are two tables previously created on my notebook, so the error does not come from forgetting to instantiate these variables.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: The unbalanced parentheses are in `word[indice]`, not `contenu`.  Without knowing the value of `word`, then there's no way to say why you're getting that error.

Comment: You need to escape the value of `word[indice]` so that it becomes a literal search instead of being tainted by unescaped meta characters. Check out this question [Escaping regex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string) and use `re.escape()`. It sounds like you don't even need regex and `.find()` should suffice.

Comment: Now that you mention it I didn't see that my word variable was badly encoded. Thanks you ! Thank you MonkeyZeus for your advice, I'll give it a try, it might be better than what I've been trying to do.